# SQLite3 duplicates

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm having difficulties with SQLite3. The table is as follow:

```
id|name
11|test1
31|test1
51|test1
13|test2
17|test2
..|..
```

I need to get only one name and all id's for that name, like this:

```
test1|array(11,31,51)
test2|array(13,17)
...
```

How can I do it with PHP and SQLite3? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? And what is given? Do you have a name and need the id-array for that or do you need that name/id-array-hash-map for the whole table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use group_concat

```
SELECT 
    name,
    group_concat(id) AS ids
FROM Table
GROUP BY name
```

will return something like

```
test1|11,31,51
test2|13,17
```

and then you can just explode the ids, to get them as array.

```
$ids_array = explode(",",$ids);
```